# Get data from mysql by table header PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have code like this:

```
$start  = new DateTime('first day of this month');
$end    = new DateTime('first day of this month + 1 month');
$period = new DatePeriod($start, new DateInterval('P1D'), $end);
foreach($period as $day){
?>



<th><?php echo $day->format('Y-M-d')."\n"; ?></th>

<?php
}
?>
```

It will show table header with date from this month

[image: table header]

I want get data from mysql and sort date by the header,
and this is my query:

```
$date = mysql_query("SELECT min(TIME(CHECKTIME)) AS timeonly,
                                  max(TIME(CHECKTIME)) AS timeonly2,
                                  DATE(CHECKTIME) AS DateOnly
                                  FROM checkinout
                                            WHERE USERID = $c[USERID] AND CHECKTIME = $day
                                            GROUP BY DateOnly
                                            ORDER BY CHECKTIME ASC");
```

I know this is wrong,
but I don't know how to sort that CHECKTIME so they will show corresponding by date from header?

What should I do with this query?

```
WHERE USERID = $c[USERID] AND CHECKTIME = $day
```

Comment: Why are you using the long-deprecated `mysql_` code library? It was discontinued many years ago and removed entirely in PHP7. No new code should be written using this library. It leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (due to the lack of parameterised query support) and potentially other unpatched vulnerabilities. Switch to using `mysqli` or `PDO` as soon as possible, and then learn how to write parameterised queries to protect your data from malicious input. See http://bobby-tables.com for a simple explanation of the risks and some sample PHP code to write queries safely.

Comment: Anyway since we have no idea what your data structure is, or what data is in the table(s), it's a little difficult to suggest how to amend the query. We need one of these: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve